# news feed graph api real time updates

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed, real-time-updates

I am developing at the moment a website where the users can read all messages from Facebook, Twitter, Email, Co.. Because the Graph Api is relativly slow I don't want to query the news feed (home) and private messages from the inbox every time. I thought I could use real time updates from Facebook. But in the documentation it says nothing about querying the news feed or inbox. Is that possible?

Comment: The docs say that the user feed connection is available for real time updates; the inbox connection however is not.